# Fake Document.visibilityState in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

Is there a way to fake the `Document.visibilityState` on an electron app? I need that for a website that doesn't correctly deal with losing focus (it only looks at `Document.visibilityState` and should be looking at blur also).

Minimizing the window works, but is not convenient.

EDIT: my use case is: I'm wrapping a website in an electron app. That website is looking at `Document.visibilityState` to know if the user is active or not. The problem is that if the user switches to another window, the visibilityState is still "visible". The site should also be looking at the blur/focus events, but it is not (it is not my website). I would like to handle the blur event myself (which I can), and fake the `Document.visibilityState` so knows that it is not visible or focused.

Comment: can you make yore question more clear ?
you wants to know it window is focused or not , it is visible or not ??

Comment: @Excalibur I just added the use case

Comment: first of all, visibilityState is readonly so if by `fake` you mean `change`, not possible. Secondly you mention that minimizing the window works but isn't convenient, but minimizing the window is all visibilityState checks for in the context of an electron app! The only other case on the web that it has a value for is when the page is a background tab, which doesn't apply in this context at all. You'll need to change the app to be less reliant on visibilityState to check if you're in a background window, because `visibilityState` can't know that.

Comment: @Asthmatic I can't change the website since I don't own it. I would fix it there if I could. I know that visibilityState only checks for the app minimizing. That is why I was asking for a way to manipulate it in electron, even if it is read only. Even if I could simulate that it becomes a background tab (without really becoming one) would work.

Comment: use Webview within app. its possible to fake webview document.visibilityState
something like this
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4879

Answer (score 4):

You can use a script resembling the one below to override the values:

```js
> document.__defineGetter__("visibilityState",  function() { return "tarun";})
undefined
> document.visibilityState
"tarun"
```

Now, the main thing is for you to determine how to you want to change the value. Shown below is how you can interact with the web page:

```js
const electron = require('electron') 
  
// Importing BrowserWindow from Main Process using Electron remote 
const BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow; 
  
var inject = document.getElementById('inject'); 
let win = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(); 
// let win = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()[0]; 
  
inject.addEventListener('click', (event) => { 
    win.webContents.executeJavaScript('const path = require("path");'
        + 'const fs = require("fs");'
        + 'fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "../assets/sample.txt"), '
        + '{encoding: "utf-8"}, function(err, data) {'
        + 'if (!err) { console.log("received data: " + data); }'
        + 'else { console.log(err); } });', true) 
        .then(console.log('JavaScript Executed Successfully')); 
}); 
  
var print = document.getElementById('print'); 
print.addEventListener('click', (event) => { 
  
    var webSource = { 
        code: 'var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];' 
        + 'function filters(num) { return num > 2; }' 
        + 'console.log(numbers.filter(filters));', 
        url: '', 
        startLine: 1 
    } 
  
    win.webContents.executeJavaScriptInIsolatedWorld(1, [webSource], true) 
        .then(console.log('JavaScript Executed Successfully')); 
});
```

PS: The above code is found at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-execute-javascript-in-electronjs/

Comment: A small remark: I would opt for `Object.defineProperty`, not `__defineGetter__`!

Comment: @Gershy, it doesn't let redefine the property, that is why I had to use `__defineGetter__`. If you try it throws `VM342:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: visibilityState
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:8`